# Admin LTE datepicker not showing up

Tags: jquery, datepicker, adminlte

I'm trying to add datepicker inside my form. Please take a look

```
<script src="http://localhost:84/new_store/assets/template/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:84/new_store/assets/template/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#datepickerss').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
  });
</script>
```

and here is the field

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepickerss">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to input, there is no calendar pop up (I don't know what it's name). And there is no error in browser console log. My HTML fullpage source code http://pastebin.com/9DDjKyNn

Comment: Make sure there is no jquery error on your page. And check "datepickerss" id should not use more than once in your page.

Comment: @YogeshShakya well, if when any jquery error, it showed up at console browser right? i cant see any error

Comment: You need to include the "bootstrap-datepicker.css" without it wont work. As I see in your code you included  "datepicker3.css" not bottstrap datepicker css.

Answer (score 3):

adding this resolved for me :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" >
```

Answer (score 1):

> I hope this will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Advanced form elements</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">  
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js">
  <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js">    
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/2.4.12/js/adminlte.min.js">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

  </head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div>
<!-- /.col (left) -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Date picker</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <!-- Date -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date:</label>

                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.form group -->             

            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->          
        </div>
        <!-- /.col (right) -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- date-range-picker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/2.4.12/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page script -->
<script>
  $(function () {
    //Date picker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true
    })
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is .daterangepicker() not datepicker()

//Date range picker

```
$('#reservation').daterangepicker()
//Date range picker with time picker
$('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({
  timePicker: true,
  timePickerIncrement: 30,
  locale: {
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
  }
})
//Date range as a button
$('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
  {
    ranges   : {
      'Today'       : [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday'   : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days' : [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month'  : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month'  : [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate  : moment()
  },
  function (start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'))
  }
)
```